# "Null" Connection jtds.jdbc1.3.1 connection to SQL server

Tags: android, sql-server

Here is all of my code. I am trying to connect to my SQL server. These contents in sentences are actually exist. Real username and passwords. But I am getting `Null` on error catch (not connected). Please let me know where the error could be.

And I also added Internet permission in manifest.
I came across from this article - [link](http://mob-programming.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-connect-and-access-sql-database.html)

```
  package com.eample.databasetester;

  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import java.sql.Connection;
  import java.sql.DriverManager;
  import java.sql.ResultSet;
  import java.sql.Statement;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      TextView txv1;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      txv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
      query2();
  }
  public void query2()
  {
      txv1.setText("connected");
  Log.i("Android"," MySQL Connect Example.");
  Connection conn = null;
  try {
  String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
  Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
  String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://50.62.209.49:3306/test;encrypt=fasle;user=XXXX;password=YYYY;instance=SQLEXPRESS;";
  String username = "XXXX";
  String password = "YYYY";
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString,username,password);
  Log.w("Connection","open");
  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
  ResultSet reset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from test");


  while(reset.next()){
      txv1.setText("Data:"+reset.getString(3));

  }
  conn.close();

  } catch (Exception e)
  {
      txv1.setText("Error connection" + e.getMessage());
  }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

THis is a really bad idea.  You should not connect to a database over the network from a phone.  First off, it requires your DB to be publically addressable which is a security risk.  Secondly, it means your password for the db is on the clients, and you don't physically control them.  Your app will be reverse engineered, they'll get your password, and then your data is fucked.  You should always abstract access to the database from any hardware you don't control by use of a webservice.  Then the password never leaves your machines and the damage an attacker can do is limited.

Third, this code wont work anyway, you cant do network IO on the UI thread.  That's likely why conn returned null.  But take this as a sign of the universe telling you to fix things the right way rather than just changing threads.